# Incorrect Url on Response.Redirect()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

Im trying to make my Swagger documentation as homepage in my API using the following code:

```
var uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());            
var swaggerUri = new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "/api/doc/index").ToString();

//Check if the Uri points to localhost
if(uri.ToString().Contains("127.0.0.1"))
     app.Run(async ctx => { ctx.Response.Redirect($"{HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath}api/doc/index"); });
else
     //Problem here
     app.Run(async ctx => { ctx.Response.Redirect(swaggerUri); });
```

The variable `swaggerUri` sets the correct url to path containing the Swagger documentation, but when i deploy the Api on IIS `app.Run(async ctx => { ctx.Response.Redirect(swaggerUri); })` redirects to the following Url:

```
http://testes/webapiapi/doc/index
```

instead of

```
http://testes/webapi/api/doc/index
```

it misses the slash after `/webapi`.

*Edits made for better clearance of the problem.

Comment: are you missing a slash in the 4rth line before api   $"{HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath}api/doc/index"); });

Comment: Hi @Thameem, this line is used to create the redirection when the application run on the localhost (127.0.0.1) and is working properly. The problem is in this line `app.Run(async ctx => { ctx.Response.Redirect(swaggerUri); });`

Comment: check the output of this {HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath}